# How do I load and unload a Python module dynamically, disassemble and inspect it, but not execute init code or add it to sys.modules?

Tags: python, inspect

I'm experimenting with disassembling Python modules into bytecodes.

Must I import a Python module statically or dynamically in order to disassemble or inspect it?  If not, what are the (pythonic, portable) ways to do it?

I'd like to:

1. Load an available Python module's binary data into memory at runtime:

   1. Without it appearing as an available module in `sys.modules`.
   2. I don't want to execute any of the module's `__init__` code, or have it added to any namespace.
   3. There should be no other side effects of loading the module.  As far as the 
      interpreter's concerned, it should just be a blob of data to be inspected.
2. Disassemble or otherwise inspect the module's classes, functions or data.
3. Unload the module when desired.

I've searched, and I see a number of methods of dynamic module importation (which has the side effect of executing module `__init__` code or other inline code, and insertion into sys.modules).  But I'd rather not deal with those side effects.

Is this possible?  If so, what approaches are most portable/Pythonic?

Comment: What would it mean to "load a module" without allowing it to execute its __init__.py file?  It seems like a contradiction to me.

Comment: Load the binary data in memory in a form that can be accessed by code, but not executed.  I've updated the question to reflect your feedback

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a bit and one possible solution is usage of the [pyclbr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pyclbr.html) module. The inspection of it looks at basic information about classes and functions, loading it into a dictionary for easy access. Here is a sample run:

```
>>> import pyclbr
>>> import sys
>>> info = pyclbr.readmodule_ex('inspect')
>>> info
{'formatargvalues': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28e50>, 'walktree': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28b50>, 'getinnerframes': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29050>, 'indentsize': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28710>, 'getmodulename': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28850>, 'formatannotation': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28d50>, 'ismemberdescriptor': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e283d0>, 'iscode': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28550>, 'getsource': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28b10>, 'formatargspec': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28dd0>, 'getabsfile': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e288d0>, 'getsourcelines': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28ad0>, '_getfullargs': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28c10>, 'isabstract': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28610>, 'isbuiltin': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28590>, 'getlineno': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28f10>, 'getcomments': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28990>, 'getgeneratorstate': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e293d0>, 'getattr_static': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29390>, 'getframeinfo': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28ed0>, 'isgenerator': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28490>, '_static_getmro': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29190>, 'isframe': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28510>, 'getouterframes': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28f90>, 'getclasstree': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28b90>, 'getfile': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e287d0>, '_shadowed_dict': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29310>, 'getargvalues': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28d10>, 'getmembers': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28650>, 'BlockFinder': <pyclbr.Class object at 0x5083e28a10>, 'isfunction': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28390>, 'getargspec': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28c50>, 'currentframe': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29090>, 'namedtuple': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e1b150>, 'getmoduleinfo': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28810>, 'trace': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29110>, 'isclass': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083db8950>, '_is_type': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29290>, 'getcallargs': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28e90>, 'ismethoddescriptor': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28310>, 'isgeneratorfunction': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28450>, 'isroutine': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e285d0>, 'getfullargspec': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28cd0>, 'getmro': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e286d0>, 'getargs': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28bd0>, 'stack': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e290d0>, 'getdoc': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28750>, 'findsource': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28950>, 'cleandoc': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28790>, '_check_class': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29250>, '_check_instance': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e29210>, 'classify_class_attrs': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28690>, 'ismodule': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083db8910>, 'EndOfBlock': <pyclbr.Class object at 0x5083e289d0>, 'isdatadescriptor': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28350>, 'getmodule': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28910>, 'formatannotationrelativeto': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28d90>, 'getsourcefile': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28890>, 'ismethod': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e282d0>, 'isgetsetdescriptor': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28410>, 'istraceback': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e284d0>, 'getblock': <pyclbr.Function object at 0x5083e28a50>}
>>> sys.modules['inspect']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'inspect'
```

Anything more advanced and you would have to start looking into accessing the abstract syntax tree through the [ast module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#module-ast).

Comment: That helps, because I do need class browser functionality but the exposed interface doesn't help me with the core requirement.  I will code dive into pyclbr to see if the implementation provides additional clues, so +1 for your answer!

Comment: @Inactivist can you expand a little more on the requirements? What kind of analysis are you expecting? Much of the more lower level interaction is handled by the [Python Language Services](http://docs.python.org/2/library/language.html) modules.

Comment: Mainly I want to get bytecode data from a module's methods (and other attributes) at runtime, but I don't want to import the module for execution.  It seems that the built-in services assume you want to or have imported the module (but I'm still searching and learning.)  I've updated my original question to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I found [uncompyle2](https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2) for Python 2.7, which contains functions to [load a source file and compile it to bytecodes](https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2/blob/master/uncompyle2/__init__.py#L35-L55) and [load a module and compile it to bytecodes](https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2/blob/master/uncompyle2/__init__.py#L57-L79) without importing the module.

So at a minimum it appears it is doable but may involve invoking `compile()` on source, or, if working with a pyc file, may not be portable (uncompyle2 supports Python 2.7 only with pyc files.)